# php delete specific txtline in textfile based on variable

Tags: php

Hey guys is there a way to delete a specific variable in a textfile? I have an textfile let's call it xyz.txt in which are the following contents:

```
sdasd
dasdasda
sadasd
```

Now im loading the content of the file with `file_get_contents`. Let the user make the decision which variable he wants to delete. Let's say he selected `sdasd`. What do i have to use when i now want to delete the line with `sdasd` from the textfile? Didn't found anything helpful here: [PHP Manual filesystem](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php)

Here is how i load the contents of the txtfile:

```
$handle = @fopen("xyz.txt", "r");
        echo ('<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">');
      echo '<thead>';
      echo'<tr>';
        echo'<th>Auswahl</th>';
        echo'<th>Admin</th>';
        echo'</tr>';
        echo'</thead>';
        echo ('<tbody>');
        echo("<tr>");
        while (!feof($handle)) // Loop til end of file.
        {
        $buffer = fgets($handle, 4096);
        // Read a line.
        list($a,$b,$c)=explode(" ",$buffer);
        //Separate string by the means of |
        echo '<td><form name="Lager" method="submit" action="admins_verwalten.php"><input type="radio" name="Admin" value="'.$a.$b.$c.'"><br></td>';
        echo('<td>'.$a.$b.$c."</td>");
        echo("</tr>");
        }
        echo ('</tbody>');
        echo ('</table>');
        echo '<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"></i>Admin delete</button></label></form>';
```

Comment: A text file doesn't contain variables, it contains ... well, text; so you need string manipulation functions instead.

Comment: Do not you want to `str_replace` `\nsdasd` and put it back?

Comment: And where is `file_get_contents` here, in code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all lines into an array:

```
$arr = file('textfile.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
```

Taking the string out:

```
$to_remove = 'asdf';
$arr = array_filter($arr, function($item) use ($to_remove) {
    return $item != $to_remove;
});
```

To write the file back:

```
file_put_contents('textfile.txt', join("\n", $arr));
```

**Edit**

To help you debug why the filtering doesn't work; for instance, this works:

```
$arr = array('HAUGMA1', 'sdasd', 'dasdasda', 'sadasd');

$to_remove = 'sdasd';
$arr = array_filter($arr, function($item) use ($to_remove) {
        return $item != $to_remove;
});

print_r($arr);
```

Comment: so i have tested it and nothing happened.So i created an echo which outputs $arr and it just say `Array`

Comment: @Pgr456 You need `print_r($arr)` if you wish to debug array contents.

Comment: this gives me `Array ( [0] => HAUGMA1 [1] => sdasd [2] => dasdasda [3] => sadasd ) `

Comment: ok it i have debuged it and it seems it doesn't filter the array

Comment: @Pgr456 The `$to_remove` should be assigned with the value of the radio input box.

Comment: yes i know did it and it is still not working and tried it with `sdasd` which is not working too.

Comment: @Pgr456 I've added a section to my answer that might help you track down why it won't work.

Comment: ok i used you're edit and find out that your filter stop wokring as soon as i link `$to_remove` to another variable

Answer (score 0):

You will have to read the file into memory to facilitate user interaction.  When the user selects which variable to delete, write the file back without the item to delete.

Comment: i already managed to load the contents in an table where the user can select each line with an radio button i don't know how write everything back without the selected

Comment: When the user returns the form, you will have to read the entire file again.  Then find the line that is being deleted, and write the file to disk without that line - effectively deleting it.

Comment: So there is no function which can do it in a simple way?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no simple function for this.  Although php does provide a few helpers that allow you to quickly edit the contents of the file.  Any method you choose will need you to read the file, find the line you want to remove, and then write the file without that line.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it:

```
1. Read contents from the file into a variable
2. use the explode with a linefeed as the delimiter to put the lines of the text file into an array.
3. take user input.
4 for each element in the array see if user input matches the value.
5. if matches then delete that element in the array.
6. recreate the text file from the array and write to disk.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this.

```
$source = "xyz.txt";
$raw = file_get_contents($source) or die("Cannot read file");
$wordlist = "sdasd";
$raw = preg_replace("/($wordlist)/ie", "", $raw);
file_put_contents($source, $raw);
```

If you want to remove multiple lines,
change

```
$wordlist = "sdasd";
```

to

```
$wordlist = "sdasd|abcd"; //this will remove abcd also if found.
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh boy, there's so much wrong in your approach, I don't even know where to begin with.

Anyways, we'll try. First let's get the view straight:

```
<?php
    // Read the contents into an array without newlines
    $content = file('xyz.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
?>
<!-- A single form is enough, we don't want a gazillion forms!!! -->
<form name="Lager" method="POST" action="admins_verwalten.php">
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Auswahl</th>
            <th>Admin</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php
        for ( $i=0; $i<$content.length; $i++ ) {
            // We don't need the line itself as the input's value,
            // line number will suffice
            // Moreover we will allow multiple lines to be deleted (that's
            // what the >> name="Admin[]" << is for
            print sprintf(
                '<tr>
                     <td><input type="radio" name="Admin[]" value="%d"></td>
                     <td>%s</td>
                 </tr>',
                $i,
                $content[$i]
            );
        }
    ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Admin delete"/>
</form>
```

Then we'll take care of the form submission handling:

```
// This will give us an array with numbers of lines to be deleted
$lines = isset($_POST['Admin']) ?
             $_POST['Admin'] : false;

if ( !empty($lines) ) {
    $content = file('xyz.txt');

    foreach ( $lines as $line ) {
        // Delete the lines chosen by the client
        unset($content[$line]);
    }

    // Write back the remaining content
    file_put_contents('xyz.txt', $content);
}
```